# My Scrapy function is never being called. What do I miss

Tags: python, scrapy

I have this general save function in scrapy spider.

```
def save_results(self, menu, url ):
        inspect_response(response,self)
        res, method = self.crawl_result(url)
        self.item['crawl_result'] = res
        self.item['raw_menu_urls'] = url
        self.item['conversion_method'] = method
        self.item['menu_text'] = menu
        print self.item
        yield self.item
```

And I call it like this from other function:

```
def yelp_menu(self, response):
        id = response.meta['id']
        menu =  response.xpath('//div[@class="container biz-menu"]//text()').extract()
        menu = self.clean_text(menu)
        self.save_results(response.url, menu)
```

But it never gets called.
Where am I wrong?
P.S. I know it is not how scrapy is supposed to work with items , pipelines and the rest.

Comment: these functions are inside a class ; or separate functions ? If there are separate functions call the save_results without the self.

Comment: @Dimitris Kougioumtzis It is inside spider class.

Comment: A couple of potential problems: `save_results()` is not a function but a generator (it uses `yield`). This means that calling it will return  a generator, it will not execute the "function". You can iterate over the generator to get all (in tour case one) value. Alternatively just `return` the value, don't `yield` it. Also `yelp_menu()` calls `save_results(response.url, menu)` but `save_results()`parameters are the other way round (`menu` first, `url` second)

Comment: @zxxc Thanks man. This happens to me all the time. Missing small (but important) things.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that `self.save_results` returns a generator. What you need is the following:

```
for item in self.save_results(response.url, menu):
    yield item
```

Or, if you're using Python 3.3+, you can use `yield from` magic:

```
yield from self.save_results(response.url, menu)
```